# JavaScript HelloWorld

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunction()
            {
                alert(“Hello World!”)
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Create a Dialog Box!</button>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Create Another Dialog Box!</button>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can somebody tell me why the JavaScript code alone is not working? The two buttons are created but nothing happens when I click on it.

I just started learning JavaScript and so not able to find the error.

Comment: Why are you using fancy `“` use `'` or `"`?

Comment: apart from the apostrophes that look weird this code should work. What error are you getting?

Comment: 1) You are not using the BASIC language (I've removed that tag) 2) You need to use a text editor, not a word processor.

Comment: the problem was with the apostrophes. Thanks a ton!! :)